# Creating Multiple Mutexes in Rust for Thread Synchronization

Tags: rust, concurrency, mutex, smart-pointers

I'm not familiar with Rust.
The program I'm trying to write will have the value of n determined at runtime.

I want the program to have the following behavior: n threads will be created, each interacting with a user and storing data (these are slave nodes). The latest data from all of these threads will be consolidated and output by a single thread (the master node).

To achieve this, I'll be using arc and mutex to share variables between individual slaves and the master. I want to declare N mutexes, but I'm not sure how to do that.

One of the challenges I'm facing is that because n is determined dynamically, I need to create a vector containing n Arcs.

If this approach is incorrect, I'm open to hearing about alternative solutions.

---

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;


fn main() {
    let n = 10;

    let mut shared_list = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    let mut thread_list = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    for _ in 0..n {
        shared_list.push(Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)));
    }

    let print_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            
            let mut sum = 0;
            for i in 0..n {
                let data = shared_list[i].lock().unwrap();
                sum += *data;
            }
            println!("shared_data = {}", sum);
    
            if sum == 10*100 {
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    thread_list.push(print_thread);

    for i in 0..n {
        let shared_data = shared_list[i].clone();
        let slave_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                let mut data = shared_data.lock().unwrap();
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3));
                *data += 1;
                println!("Thread {}: data = {}", i, *data);
                
                if *data == 100{
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        thread_list.push(slave_thread);
    }
    
    
    for handle in thread_list {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

---

**Update** The program that will be written should have n threads that continuously receive matrices from the user. Additionally, a separate thread should be included that collects the last saved matrices from each individual thread, regardless of their input operations, and performs additional operations on them. I understand that this is a very specific scenario.

I will share a toy program that is closer to the original scenario.

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use ndarray::Array2;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let n = 10;
    let mut thread_handles = Vec::new();
    let mut shared_list = Vec::with_capacity(n);

    for _ in 0..n {
        shared_list.push(Arc::new(Mutex::new(Array2::zeros((0, 0)))));
    }
    
    let shared_data_clone = shared_list.clone();
    let output_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut loop_t = 0;

        loop {
            for i in 0..n {
                let data = shared_data_clone[i].lock().unwrap();
                
            /// something...
            }
            loop_t += 1;
        }
    });
    thread_handles.push(output_thread);
    

    for i in 0..n {
        let shared_data_clone = shared_list[i].clone();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut loop_t = 0;
            loop {
                let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
                let m = rng.gen::<u32>() % 9 + 1; 

                let matrix = Array2::from_shape_fn((m as usize, 3), |_| rng.gen_range(1..10)); 
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3));

                loop_t += 1;

                let mut data = shared_data_clone.lock().unwrap();
                *data = matrix;

                let sum: i32 = data.iter().sum();
                //println!("Thread {} generated matrix:{}", i, sum);
            }
        });
        thread_handles.push(handle);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds more like the use for `std::mpsc::channel` I think, can you provide some [mre] with what you've tried and the error you're getting.

Comment: @caface25 Thanks for the quick response. I just briefly asked about the skeleton of the program I'm currently working on. I'll be uploading the toy program soon.

Comment: This is really too vague and broad to give a concrete answer. `Vec<Arc<Mutex<_>>>` is a perfectly serviceable data structure, though if the master node would simply be looking within the mutexes to see if there's new content, then yeah channel-based communication would probably be better.

Comment: If all you need is the end result, the best thing to do return the value through the thread handle. You can also use [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.6.1/rayon/index.html), which is more flexible than making threads yourself. Otherwise `Vec<Arc<Mutex<_>>>` is fine. If you can edit in a specific use case, we'll be able to give better advice.

Comment: @kmdreko Channel based communication would have the drawback that the master will have to process **every** change. A mutex based one would allow the main thread to only check in from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me fix your code in the simplest way possible. Then, I'll talk about why your solution is non-ideal and what better alternatives would be.

---

The problem you have at hand is that the *"error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `shared_list`"*.

Fixing this is simple. You move the `shared_list` variable into the primary thread **before** you use it again later to spawn the other threads.

Simply swap those two. Create the threads first and **then** move it into the primary thread.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let n = 10;

    let mut shared_list = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    let mut thread_list = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    for _ in 0..n {
        shared_list.push(Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)));
    }

    for i in 0..n {
        let shared_data = shared_list[i].clone();
        let slave_thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let mut data = shared_data.lock().unwrap();
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3));
            *data += 1;
            println!("Thread {}: data = {}", i, *data);

            if *data == 100 {
                break;
            }
        });
        thread_list.push(slave_thread);
    }

    let print_thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let mut sum = 0;
        for i in 0..n {
            let data = shared_list[i].lock().unwrap();
            sum += *data;
        }
        println!("shared_data = {}", sum);

        if sum == 10 * 100 {
            break;
        }
    });
    thread_list.push(print_thread);

    for handle in thread_list {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

```
Thread 0: data = 1
Thread 1: data = 1
Thread 3: data = 1
Thread 2: data = 1
Thread 6: data = 1
Thread 8: data = 1
Thread 5: data = 1
Thread 4: data = 1
...
Thread 6: data = 100
Thread 9: data = 100
Thread 5: data = 100
Thread 0: data = 100
Thread 2: data = 100
Thread 1: data = 100
Thread 4: data = 100
shared_data = 921
shared_data = 1000
```

---

Now let's talk about the problems.

Note that `shared_data =` does not get printed a **single** time before all threads are done. That's because all of your threads are continuously holding the mutexes, even while sleeping; therefore your primary thread is continuously and desperately waiting for the next mutex to be released.

There are more problems, though:

- `Mutex<i32>` is an anti-pattern, use `AtomicI32`. Although I guess your real data might have more complex data, actually requiring a `Mutex`.
- `Arc` is not needed at all, at least in the code you show - you can use references instead. Note that this will require [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html), because references to the outside only work in scoped threads. Otherwise the compiler can't guarantee that the reference gets dropped before the actual data in `main` does.
- Your primary thread never waits. If it's your intention to compute the intermediate result with 100% CPU power over and over again, then you achieved that - if not, you should add a sleep somewhere.
- All of your data points are locked individually - that means, when the primary thread finishes its iteration, the other data most likely already changed, and your result is void. Would it be benefitial to only have a single piece of data that all threads modify? If not, no problem - it might still make sense, though, to propagate the combined data to a single point and not have one thread iterate over the vector continuously. Although this point depends heavily on the usecase, so your layout may make sense for your situation.
- Don't use `for i in 0..n { data[i] }` to loop over a vector - it's slow and C-style. The `[]` operator in Rust has overhead because it performs out-of-bounds checking. Use the for loop directly to iterate over it, like `for elem in data {}`, or use iterators. Iterators in your case would make more sense, because they even offer a `.sum()` option.
- Don't even spawn your primary thread - use the main thread directly. It's just in idle, waiting for all the threads.

Here is some inspiration. For readability I reduced the number of iterations to `2`:

- `scope` and `Atomic`s:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let n = 10;

    let mut shared_list = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..n {
        shared_list.push(AtomicI32::new(0));
    }

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        for (i, shared_data) in shared_list.iter().enumerate() {
            s.spawn(move || loop {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3));
                let data = shared_data.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed) + 1;
                println!("Thread {}: data = {}", i, data);

                if data == 2 {
                    break;
                }
            });
        }

        loop {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2));
            let sum: i32 = shared_list
                .iter()
                .map(|data| data.load(Ordering::Relaxed))
                .sum();

            println!("shared_data = {}", sum);

            if sum == 10 * 2 {
                break;
            }
        }

        // No need for joining - The threads get joined automatically
        // at the end of the scope.
    })
}
```

```
shared_data = 0
Thread 0: data = 1
Thread 1: data = 1
Thread 2: data = 1
Thread 4: data = 1
Thread 7: data = 1
Thread 8: data = 1
Thread 3: data = 1
Thread 9: data = 1
Thread 5: data = 1
Thread 6: data = 1
shared_data = 10
Thread 0: data = 2
Thread 1: data = 2
Thread 2: data = 2
Thread 4: data = 2
Thread 7: data = 2
Thread 8: data = 2
Thread 3: data = 2
shared_data = 17
Thread 5: data = 2
Thread 9: data = 2
Thread 6: data = 2
shared_data = 20
```

- `Arc<Mutex<>>`, but done properly (in my opinion):

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let n = 10;

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        let mut shared_list = vec![];
        for i in 0..n {
            let shared_data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
            shared_list.push(Arc::clone(&shared_data));

            s.spawn(move || loop {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3));
                // First sleep, then lock. Otherwise the lock is held during
                // sleep, blocking whoever waits for the lock.
                let new_data = {
                    let mut data = shared_data.lock().unwrap();
                    *data += 1;
                    *data
                    // Release the lock here again, so it isn't held
                    // during `println`.
                };

                println!("Thread {}: data = {}", i, new_data);

                if new_data == 2 {
                    break;
                }
            });
        }

        loop {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2));
            let sum = shared_list
                .iter()
                .map(|data| *data.lock().unwrap())
                .sum::<i32>();

            println!("shared_data = {}", sum);

            if sum == 10 * 2 {
                break;
            }
        }

        // No need for joining - The threads get joined automatically
        // at the end of the scope.
    })
}
```

```
shared_data = 0
Thread 0: data = 1
Thread 2: data = 1
Thread 1: data = 1
Thread 3: data = 1
Thread 4: data = 1
Thread 5: data = 1
Thread 6: data = 1
Thread 8: data = 1
Thread 9: data = 1
Thread 7: data = 1
shared_data = 10
Thread 2: data = 2
Thread 0: data = 2
Thread 1: data = 2
Thread 3: data = 2
Thread 4: data = 2
Thread 5: data = 2
Thread 7: data = 2
shared_data = 17
Thread 8: data = 2
Thread 9: data = 2
Thread 6: data = 2
shared_data = 20
```

There are probably way more ways to solve this, like incorporating [`mpsc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/) or using only one global variable instead of a vector of many. But I think this post is long enough :) Maybe this gave you a couple of ideas to continue your quest.

---

**EDIT:** Here is an example of having only one global shared variable for statistics data.

The principle is that the printing thread doesn't actively query the data from the threads, but instead the data is private to each thread and not shared with anyone. The threads themselves then push changes into the printing thread.

This has the advantage that you can use a `Condvar` to keep the printing thread dormant until a change happens, causing it to respond quick and snappy.

While I do like `std::thread::scope`, I chose not to use it here to stay closer to your original code. Normally I do use it wherever I can, though, because it's just a really nice concept.

Like this:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

struct InnerAggregateData {
    // The actual global data
    sum: i32,
    // For notifying the watcher thread of changes
    data_changed: bool,
}

struct AggregateData {
    inner: Mutex<InnerAggregateData>,
    condvar: Condvar,
}
impl AggregateData {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Mutex::new(InnerAggregateData {
                sum: 0,
                data_changed: true,
            }),
            condvar: Condvar::new(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let n = 5;
    let num_iters = 3;

    let mut threads = vec![];

    let aggregate_data = Arc::new(AggregateData::new());

    for i in 0..n {
        let aggregate_data = Arc::clone(&aggregate_data);
        threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut local_data = 0;
            loop {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200));

                // Store previous local data
                let previous_data = local_data;

                // Update local data
                local_data += 1;
                println!("Thread {}: data = {}", i, local_data);

                // Compute difference
                let diff = local_data - previous_data;

                // Update global data
                let mut global_data = aggregate_data.inner.lock().unwrap();
                global_data.sum += diff;

                // Signal global data that it changed
                global_data.data_changed = true;
                // Important: trigger the condvar while the lock is still held.
                // Otherwise there would be a race condition that could cause
                // a deadlock.
                aggregate_data.condvar.notify_all();

                if local_data == num_iters {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    threads.push(thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let locked_data = aggregate_data.inner.lock().unwrap();
        let mut locked_data = aggregate_data
            .condvar
            .wait_while(locked_data, |data| !data.data_changed)
            .unwrap();

        // Reset the `data_changed` variable
        locked_data.data_changed = false;

        // Extract data from lock
        let sum = locked_data.sum;

        // IMPORTANT: drop lock as soon as we have all the data, otherwise we
        // will block all the threads that try to write into the data.
        drop(locked_data);

        // Further processing without a locked mutex. This is allowed to take
        // long, and could even contain a `sleep` without blocking any other
        // threads.
        println!("shared_data = {}", sum);

        if sum == n * num_iters {
            break;
        }
    }));

    for handle in threads {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

```
shared_data = 0
Thread 0: data = 1
Thread 1: data = 1
shared_data = 1
Thread 4: data = 1
shared_data = 3
Thread 3: data = 1
Thread 2: data = 1
shared_data = 4
shared_data = 5
... sleep ...
Thread 1: data = 2
Thread 0: data = 2
shared_data = 6
shared_data = 7
Thread 4: data = 2
Thread 2: data = 2
shared_data = 8
Thread 3: data = 2
shared_data = 9
shared_data = 10
... sleep ...
Thread 1: data = 3
Thread 0: data = 3
shared_data = 12
Thread 4: data = 3
shared_data = 13
Thread 2: data = 3
Thread 3: data = 3
shared_data = 14
shared_data = 15
```

Note that the `shared_data =` reacts quickly to changes, but does not cause a jam. It is still capable of skipping a change if another change occured simultaneously; for example in my output, it didn't print `shared_data = 2`.

Comment: Contrary to what @Finomnis was concerned about, I did not use AtomicI32 because what I wanted to share was not an integer, but a matrix. But, thank you for all comments that helped me to write better code.

Comment: @Dev.fennek Figured, that's why I wrote *"although I guess your real data might have more complex data"*. It was just a side-note to mention that atomics exist :)

Comment: I've recorded the situation I'm in with more detail. Could you provide further comments, if possible? 

1. The output thread must operate separately from the main thread, and 2. I want the output thread to display real-time information from the input side. As you mentioned, the problem occurs because the output thread cannot release the lock.

Comment: @Dev.fennek Your example doesn't help much. The real question is - why does the one thread have to collect the data? Why is there not just simply one shared 'aggregate' data somewhere that is locked and gets updated by all threads? I added a new example to demonstrate what I mean - that's how I would probably tackle your situation.

Comment: I encountered limitations due to using the publish/subscribe feature in ROS that I mentioned earlier. I appreciate your understanding of the situation and the valuable comments you provided. Your comments have helped me to gain a better understanding of Rust.